# Cloud Firestore: retrieving cached data via direct get?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Retrieving data from the server may take some seconds. Is there any way to retrieve cached data in the meantime, using a direct get?

The `onComplete` seems to be called only when the data is retrieved from the server:

```
db.collection("cities").whereEqualTo("state", "CA").get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                ...
                }
            }
        });
```

Is there any callback for the cached data?

Comment: If the data is available from the cache, you can get it with: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data and then checking `querySnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache()`.

Comment: Also mention that if the cache does not contain data for a particular document, or the document does not exist, the get call returns an error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen As far as I understand, such example uses a listener. Is it possible to do that also with a direct get?

Comment: Yes and is also mentioned in Frank's link at the bottom of the page, "Querying works with offline persistence. You can retrieve the results of queries with either a direct get or by listening, as described in the preceding sections.". So please see the preceding sections of the offical documentation.

Comment: The only example there is using `addSnapshotListener` instead of a direct get. If you know how to achieve via a direct get, can you please post a snippet? Thanks

Comment: I just tested and getting a document with [this code from the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) continues to work when I'm offline.

Answer (score 7):

Now it is possible to load data only from cached version. From [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=1#source_options)

> You can specify the source option in a get() call to change the default behavior.....you can fetch from only the offline cache.

If it fails, then you can again try for the online version.

Example:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");

// Source can be CACHE, SERVER, or DEFAULT.
Source source = Source.CACHE;

// Get the document, forcing the SDK to use the offline cache
docRef.get(source).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Document found in the offline cache
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            Log.d(TAG, "Cached document data: " + document.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cached get failed: ", task.getException());
            //try again with online version
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran a few tests in an Android app to see how this works.

The code you need is the same, no matter if you're getting data from the cache or from the network:

```
    db.collection("translations").document("rPpciqsXjAzjpComjd5j").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            System.out.println("isFromCache: "+snapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache());
        }
    });
```

When I'm online this prints:

> isFromCache: false

When I go offline, it prints:

> isFromCache: true

There is no way to force retrieval from the cache while you're connected to the server.

If instead I use a listener:

```
    db.collection("translations").document("rPpciqsXjAzjpComjd5j").addSnapshotListener(new DocumentListenOptions().includeMetadataChanges(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                System.out.println("listen.isFromCache: "+snapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache());
            }
        }
    );
```

I get two prints when I'm online:

> isFromCache: true
>
> isFromCache: false

Comment: It would be very useful to get data also from the cache, even if there is an internet connection, as it takes seconds to get data from the server.

Comment: Agreed. But such an API currently doesn't exist yet. I'd recommend attaching a listener if speed is your concern.

Comment: I think this problem can be resolved by adding a flag in the API, something like onlyFetchFromCache(true) so server won't be hit this time and developers can achieve my goals. At the moment I am in a scenario that I have some static data at firebase and I want to get it fetched once, Application should stay online and this fetch should only happen once whenever user open the app I would like it to fetch data only for first install/open. After that I want to read it from cache all the time.

Comment: Sorry, I guess below answer has the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable network access and run the query to access data from cache .
For firestore :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#disable_and_enable_network_access
For firebase database call `db.goOffline()` and `db.goOnline()`