# Cloud firestore read count in StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**Firebase structure:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

I'm using a `StreamBuilder` for document `uid` like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: _stream(), 
    builder: (BuildContext _, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
      // this block may get called several times because of `build` function
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final user = snapshot.data; 
        return SomeWidget(user: user);
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
}
```

---

**Questions:**

1. Since `StreamBuilder`'s `builder` may get called several times because of the `build()` method, will that cost me a read every time `builder` gets called?
2. Is there any difference in terms of read-count when reading complete `uid` vs reading `uid/education`?
3. If I update `age` and `name` value, will that count as one-write or two-writes in terms of firebase write-count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore charges on every document read, write and delete therefore:

> Since StreamBuilder's builder may get called several times because of the build() method, will that cost me a read every time builder gets called?

Yes, if you are reading(retrieving) one document each time, then you will be charged as one read.

> Is there any difference in terms of read-count when reading complete uid vs reading uid/education

No difference. The read is done in the document, when you retrieve one document then you are doing one read.

> If I update age and name value, will that count as one-write or two-writes in terms of firebase write-count?

If you update one document once (even if all the fields are updated), it will cost you one write operation.

Comment: **StreamBuilder's builder may get called several times because of the build() method, will that cost me a read every time builder gets called ?** I don't think so because firebase cache data so the stream builder will use the cached one instead of retrieving from the network.

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222713/cloud-firestore-retrieving-cached-data-via-direct-get